# Get all Actions filtered by Verb with Django Activity Stream

Tags: django, django-activity-stream

I'm quite new to Django and Python, so maybe my Question might be stupid but..

I'm logging what users do on my page with Django-Activity-Stream.

And now I'm trying to build a page where I'll have a nice graph showing me what users did depending on the action and date.

So far so well, until now I did it with a raw sql query but since Django's not supposed to be used like this, I want to count actions filtered by the verb it's allocated to.

My raw query looks like:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM actstream_action WHERE verb = %s "
"AND '2018-06-01' <= timestamp AND '2018-06-30' >= timestamp", ['User created'])
row = cursor.fetchone()
return row[0]
```

I hope somebody could help me!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could import the `actstream.models.Action` class and query on it.

For example, to get a `queryset` of all actions with the verb ***added new post*** that was generated between **20th and 24th September 2018**, you could do this

```
import datetime
from actstream.models import Action

start = datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 20)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 24)
actions = Action.objects.filter(verb='added new post', timestamp__gt=start, timestamp__lt=end)
```